# Keep getting this error when I'm trying to compile with Gradle in Android Studio on UBUNTU 14.04

Tags: android, ubuntu, gradle

```
Error:org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: A problem occurred starting process 'command '/home/codywang/Documents/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/21.1.2/aapt'' :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
Error: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: A problem occurred starting process 'command '/home/codywang/Documents/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/21.1.2/aapt''
```

I kept getting these errors when I'm trying to compile in Ubuntu 14.04 from Android Studio 1.1.

I have done some research on the internet, and found out this might caused by my 64-bit Ubuntu which incompatible with the 32-bit android-sdk

So I tried the following commands in order to install i386 packages.

```
$ sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libstdc++6:i386 lib32z1 libsdl1.2debian:i386
```

I've installed all of those libs, but still got the same error.
Any ideas of how to solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked if you have proper permission on this file? /home/codywang/Documents/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/21.1.2/aapt

Answer (score 3):

change directorty to **build-tools/21.1.2/** directory and run following command

```
chmod +x aidl dexdump bcc_compat dx llvm-rs-cc mainDexClasses zipalign arm-linux-androideabi-ld i686-linux-android-ld mipsel-linux-android-ld
```